# How to use javascript code inside angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to add this javascript code to my html component (template) but it doesn't work.Do you have any idea how to do it ?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $().ready(function() {
      $sidebar = $('.sidebar');

      $sidebar_img_container = $sidebar.find('.sidebar-background');

      $full_page = $('.full-page');

      $sidebar_responsive = $('body > .navbar-collapse');

      window_width = $(window).width();

      fixed_plugin_open = $('.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper .nav li.active a p').html();

      if (window_width > 767 && fixed_plugin_open == 'Dashboard') {
        if ($('.fixed-plugin .dropdown').hasClass('show-dropdown')) {
          $('.fixed-plugin .dropdown').addClass('open');
        }

      }


  });
</script>
```

I appreciate your help !

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to add script-tags in your template html. The main reason why to avoid this is that you run your code outside the "Angular context" (outside Zone.js). Use the component.ts file for your code to assure it is executed as expected.

It is also not recommended to use jQuery with Angular, as almost every functionality of jQuery is provided via the Angular framework.

Maybe you describe what you want to do achieve with the script snippet, there will be a "Angular way" to do so.

Comment: The js and jquery code that i posted is for a dashboard template that i downloaded,that's why i am trying to make it work inside angular.Is there anyway to use the js and jquery inside Angular without using the component.ts ?

Comment: I don't know how, i assume it should work the way you posted, but a full example would be necessary to reproduce it (i assume that is why you get so many downvotes).
add some more console.logs to assure that the code runs and has the states you assume it should have. Another hint is to understand the code and the purpose of it. The first four lines of the ready-callback function in the snippet you posted are completely uselss. Maybe the template you downloaded is not the dashboard you should use in an angular context...

Comment: I tried to add the full code but the editor denied to add a post that contains a lot of codes,that's why i made it short and i explained my point.